# Lua: Semantic Similarity using Neural Networks

Tags: lua, torch

I'm new to Lua programming and I'm trying to execute the semantic similarity using neural network. I get a code in https://github.com/hohoCode/textSimilarityConvNet

And it has,

```
include('Conv.lua')
modelTrained = torch.load("download_local_location/modelSTS.trained.th", 'ascii')
modelTrained.convModel:evaluate()
modelTrained.softMaxC:evaluate()
local linputs = torch.zeros(rigth_sentence_length, emd_dimension)
linpus = XassignEmbeddingValuesX
local rinputs = torch.zeros(left_sentence_length, emd_dimension)
rinpus = XassignEmbeddingValuesX

local part2 = modelTrained.convModel:forward({linputs, rinputs})
local output = modelTrained.softMaxC:forward(part2)
local val = torch.range(0, 5, 1):dot(output:exp()) 
return val/5
```

when I run the code it shows

```
attempt to call global 'include' (a nil value)
```

But I've placed the Conv.lua file in same location. Can someone suggest me to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting this error message because textSimilarityConvNet expects there to be a global `include` function that it can use, but that function has not been loaded.

In Lua, values that are not defined default to `nil`, which is why you see the error you do. You're asking Lua to call the `include` function, but the variable called `include` isn't a function, so it can't be called.

The `include` function is a part of the Torch library (it is defined [here](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/e17f93ae8976a611cbda9f619ed129614e1c443d/init.lua#L48)), so the fundamental cause of your problem is probably that Torch isn't installed correctly. Try checking the [installation page](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html) to see if you have missed any steps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it really useful.https://stackoverflow.com/users/5287638/jack-taylor

Comment: Hi, Now the code is executing but it requires to include a module(similarityMeasure) from torch. I've already installed torch but i dont know why its not picking it. Please guide me to solve this issue.
The error is at the below line of the code,
    local Conv = torch.class('similarityMeasure.Conv')

Comment: We will need more information to solve your new problem. It's probably easiest if you ask it as a new question, and include a link to this question when you ask your new one.

Comment: Hi Jack, I've raised the new question in following url, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234734/lua-similaritymeasure-is-an-invalid-module-name