# SimilarityMeasure is an invalid module name

Tags: lua, torch

This is a follow-up to my earlier question [Lua: Semantic Similarity using Neural Networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212122).

For Semantic similarity I've execute the following code,

```
include('Conv.lua')
modelTrained = torch.load("download_local_location/modelSTS.trained.th", 'ascii')
modelTrained.convModel:evaluate()
modelTrained.softMaxC:evaluate()
local linputs = torch.zeros(rigth_sentence_length, emd_dimension)
linpus = XassignEmbeddingValuesX
local rinputs = torch.zeros(left_sentence_length, emd_dimension)
rinpus = XassignEmbeddingValuesX

local part2 = modelTrained.convModel:forward({linputs, rinputs})
local output = modelTrained.softMaxC:forward(part2)
local val = torch.range(0, 5, 1):dot(output:exp()) 
return val/5
```

And Execute it using the following command in terminal,

```
> th similarity.lua
```

But the error it displays is,

```
while creating metatable similarityMeasure.Conv: bad argument #1 (similarityMeasure is an invalid module name)
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'newmetatable'
/torch/install/share/lua/5.2/torch/init.lua:102: in function 'class'
.../textSimilarityConvNet-master/Conv.lua:1: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'dofile'
/torch/install/share/lua/5.2/paths/init.lua:84: in function 'dofile'
/torch/install/share/lua/5.2/torch/init.lua:49: in function 'include'
similarity.lua:1: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'dofile'
.../torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
[C]: in ?
```

First few lines in Conv.lua is,

```
local Conv = torch.class('similarityMeasure.Conv')

function Conv:__init(config)
  self.mem_dim       = config.mem_dim       or 150
  self.learning_rate = config.learning_rate or 0.01
  self.batch_size    = config.batch_size    or 1 --25
  self.num_layers    = config.num_layers    or 1
  self.reg           = config.reg           or 1e-4
  self.structure     = config.structure     or 'lstm' -- {lstm, bilstm}
  self.sim_nhidden   = config.sim_nhidden   or 150
  self.task          = config.task          or 'sic'  -- or 'vid'

  -- word embedding
  self.emb_vecs = config.emb_vecs
  self.emb_dim = config.emb_vecs:size(2)
```

Please guide me to solve this.

Comment: Posting [links](https://github.com/castorini/MP-CNN-Torch) to the libraries you are trying to use would've been useful for answering.

Comment: Note: this is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212122).

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the similarityMeasure module (and likely other modules as well). I'm guessing that the things you are missing are dependencies that are not included with the default Torch installation. The [installation instructions](https://github.com/hohoCode/textSimilarityConvNet#installation-and-dependencies) in the Github respository's readme file say the following:

> Please install Torch deep learning library. We recommend this local
>   installation which includes all required packages our tool needs,
>   simply follow the instructions here: https://github.com/torch/distro

If you installed Torch some other way, try doing it using the linked distro instead and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: While Installing torch distro it throws following error, But i'm downloaded the directory from git,

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
    Installing Lua version: LUAJIT21
    CMake Error at exe/CMakeLists.txt:1 (ADD_SUBDIRECTORY):
      The source directory
        ...../distro-master/exe/luajit-rocks
      does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Also the repo has been recently updated. 
https://github.com/castorini/MP-CNN-Torch

Once you installed the torch library properly, then you can check and see the newly added/provided testDeployment.lua file, as an example to see how to use the trained model properly.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Now the code is executed but i cannot load the pre-trained model file of modelSTS.trained.th in testDeployTrainedModel.lua file. It throws 


/torch/install/share/lua/5.2/torch/File.lua:353: in function 'readObject'
/torch/install/share/lua/5.2/torch/File.lua:409: in function 'load'
testDeployTrainedModel.lua:85: in main chunk......

Can someone suggest me to solve this.

Comment: I placed the full logs in the following url,  Can someone guide me to solve this
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/torch7/bfvlLi6tBPs

Comment: One possible reason is you memory may be limited. Just one possible reason this model loading step is not working..